# Using reCaptcha with Rails 2.3.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, recaptcha

So I'm trying to get reCaptcha to render on a partial form view that uses HAML.  I have tried using the `:ruby` filter and then adding `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` but that didn't work, neither has anything else that I've found.  Is there a way to implement this?

---

### *Revision

---

Ahem, more specifically, can anyone tell me what I need to have for the `<%= recaptcha_tags %>`  helper?  Every thing I find on this subject just says "Add `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` wherever you want it to appear!" and absolutely nothing on what the helper should contain.

---

### *Another Revision

---

I am indeed trying to use Ambethia.  I tried using just `= recaptcha_tags` but that didn't work, I got an error saying it was an undefined variable or method.  I installed the Ambethia/reCaptcha as a plugin using `script/plugin install git://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha.git` and I put `config.gem "ambethia-recaptcha", :lib => "recaptcha/rails", :source => "http://gems.github.com"` in `environment.rb` along with my public/private keys.

---

### *Started Over

---

Okay, got rid of everything I had done initially.  Can anyone help me with this?  I follow all of the tutorials I can find on it, but none of them explain how to implement/create the helpers for `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` or `<%= verify_recaptcha %>`.  I'm obviously new to RoR and implementing reCaptcha of any kind, so I'm sorry I'm asking for my hand to be held but I am honestly lost and am not finding any guidance anywhere!  Thanks so much anyone and everyone.

Comment: Probably not the problem, but you'd do one or the other (gem or plugin), not both.  What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Using Rails 2.3.12 and Ruby 1.8.7-352

Answer (score 2):

did you try simply:

```
= recaptcha_tags
```

You don't mention the plugin you're using.  I'm assuming [this one](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha).  If that's the case, the `recaptcha_tags` helper will return the HTML for the captcha, and you'd insert it into whichever forms you wanted the captcha to appear on.

The `<%= %>` around `recaptcha_helper` aren't part of the helper, but rather the way you insert content into erb templates (and other templating languages resembling erb).  In Haml you don't need the surrounding tag.  It's just `=`.

Comment: This didn't help, I added a revision explaining what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I finally solved it realizing that my form was called asynchronously.

I added:

**= recaptcha_tags :ajax => true**

and captcha appeared.

Hope this could help the original question.